# How to sort a MySQL table with null column values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following schema. I need to sort table by **points**, and if rows wiith **img_link** present (not *null*) come first also. Simply need to do is - sort by *int column*, then by *varchar column*.

```
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id  | name   | img_link  |  points   |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 11  | smpl   | path.jpg  |  10       |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 12  | main   |  null     |  20       |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 13  | abcd   |  null     |  10       |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 14  | xyls   | img_.png  |  10       |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Need a result like

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 12  |
+-----+
| 11  |
+-----+
| 14  |
+-----+
| 13  |
+-----+
```

Comment: "sort by int column , then by varchar column" And have you actually tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically wrote out in words exactly what you need to do.

```
SELECT id FROM someTable ORDER BY points DESC, img_link DESC;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6448d/2)

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY points DESC ,ISNULL(img_link), img_link
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is

```
select *
from table
order by `points` desc,
if(img_link = '' or img_link is null,1,0)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67a6a/1)**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from tabalename where img_link is not null order by point desc union select * from tabalename where img_link is null order by point desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY points DESC, img_link IS NULL, img_link DESC;
```